# Breeze System.InvalidCastException with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, breeze

Can't get data. I can see the data in visual studio. But I can'get the web front end to display the data when I go to site `mycomputername:21290/breeze/breeze/getdata`. I get this exception: Unable to cast object of type 'MySqlEntities' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.

Do I have to have odata controller?

```
public class BreezeController: ApiController
{
private readonly IRepository _repo;

..

[HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<MySqlType> GetData()
        {
            return _repo.GetData();
        }

}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
private readonly EFContextProvider<MySqlEntities> 
            _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<MySqlEntities>();

 public IQueryable<MySqlType> GetData()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.TableA;
        }

}
```

Auto-generated code in Designer.cs 
MySqlEntities : ObjectContext

Comment: Is `MySqlEntities` derived from `DbContext` or `ObjecContext` ?

Comment: ObjectContext. Audto-generated code in the edmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is in the error message: EFContextProvider expects a compatible type - something that can be cast to System.Data.Entity.DbContext; not your MySqlEntities type.

So this line:

```
private readonly EFContextProvider<MySqlEntities> 
        _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<MySqlEntities>();
```

in you Repository class should be provided with a compatible db context.

See the Breeze tutorials: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider

For future, it would be clearer if you elaborated what MySqlEntities is in code.

Comment: MySqlEntities is auto-generated in the edmx as ObjectContext. It has to be a dbcontext?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the documentation. Once I use vs2013 to generate the edmx, MySqlEntities is derived from DbContext. MySqlEntites was generated from vs2010 as derived from ObjectContext. The documentation indicate both DbContext and ObjectContext will work but instead of figuring out why it doesn't, I'm good with upgrading to using DbContext instead.